# ¿como meter letras dentro de una imagen de fondo en Html5?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css3, foundation

podrian decirme o aconsejarme como puedo meter las letras dentro de la imagen sin hacerle esto al estilo de las letras:`margin-top:-100;` ya que si hago eso afecta lo responsivo de la imagen, el framework que uso es Foundation.js.
gracias de ante mano.
les dejo una foto de como lo tengo ahorita,[image: foto de como lo tengo]

Comment: ¿Qué código tienes? La solución (o soluciones) dependerán en gran medida del código HTML que tengas y de si se puede modificar o no.

Answer (score 3):

Una forma para hacer lo que quieres sería crear un `div` con el tamaño exacto de la imagen y mediante `css` agregarle la propiedad `background-image: url()` junto con los estilos que ocupes para el texto

```css
.container {
  float: left;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url('http://static.vix.com/es/sites/default/files/styles/thumbnail/public/btg/curiosidades.batanga.com/files/8-sorprendentes-cosas-que-no-sabias-sobre-los-gatos.jpg?itok=wKHJNNav');
}

.container2 {
  float: left;
  color: black;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url('https://tuapppara.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/mejoresvideosanimales.jpg');
}
```

```html
<div class="container">Soy un gato</div>
<div class="container2">Soy un perro</div>
```

Comment: me ha servido mucho tu respuesta, de ante mano gracias.

Comment: @HolaSoyAnza si te ha servido, no te olvides de marcarla como aceptada